# Passenger side power windows stopped working

Tags: subaru, forester

Both of my passenger side windows stopped working at the same time.  The back one could not be operated by either the drivers side switches or the switch on the door itself.  The front passenger side window lowered, but would not close after it was opened.  The child protection switch is not on, besides the drivers side back window still lowers.  So does the drivers side window.  I am hoping there is just some sort of sequence of this or that I can perform to correct it.  I don't believe both motors would fail at the same time.  Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year of Forester is this?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt a fuse (but still worth checking), but the chance of some loose or poor connections or even broken wires between the door and the body are likely issues.

The broken wires are most likely in the area close to the motors ie nearside - it is probably not the drivers side even though there are switches for all the doors there...

Comment: So I had my car in the auto body shop. Realized it must have been something they did when taking off the door. I took it back to them and they corrected it. Not sure what the exact problem was but at least they took care of it at no cost. I suspect lose wires or incomplete reconstruction of door, but not sure of the details. Maybe someone else knows what they must have done. I will email them and find out!